# Fancybox 1.3.4 Inline on a button

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

Ok.. I have something similar to this setup:

```
<button id="buynow" disabled>Add to Cart</button>

<div style="display:none">
    <div id="purchase_popup">
        Content within here
    </div>
</div>
```

Then my fancybox code is this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#buynow").fancybox({
        'href'              : '#purchase_popup',
        'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
        'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
        'titleShow'         : false
    });
</script>
```

But for some odd reason, my purchase_popup div will not popup when I click the buynow button. I have that disabled so it doesn't lead to a different page since that's it's current action in this project that I just got involved with.
I don't know if the 'href' in the fancybox attributes it catching or if that's the wrong way of doing it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Disabled elements don't fire mouse events. Most browsers will propagate an event 
originating from the disabled element up the DOM tree, so event handlers 
could be placed on container elements.
```

Firefox, and perhaps other browsers, disable DOM events on form fields that are disabled.
Any event that starts at the disabled form field is completely canceled and does not propagate up the DOM tree. If you click on the disabled button, the source of the event is the disabled button and the click event is completely wiped out.
The browser literally doesn't know the button got clicked, nor does it pass the click event on. It's as if you are clicking on a black hole on the web page.

So you will have to either remove disabled attribute of button, or another work-around is, you can put outer container, on which you can fire click something like this :

```
<div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;">
  <button id="buynow" disabled>Add to Cart</button>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 1):

Some comments :

1). If your `button` is `disabled`, there is no way you can trigger an action after a `click`.

2). You need to wrap your fancybox script inside the `.ready()` method.

3). Since you are using fancybox v1.3.4 and `inline` content, you need to be aware of **[this BUG](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/fancybox/-re22BoXOzM)** and workaround.

So you could use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buynow").fancybox({
        'href': '#purchase_popup',
        'transitionIn': 'fade',
        'transitionOut': 'fade',
        'titleShow': false,
        // fix for inline nested DIVs
        'onCleanup': function () {
            var myContent = this.href;
            $(myContent).unwrap();
        }
    })
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LRR3J/)**